# Determining type in a functional language

Tags: dimension, typechecking, syntax-checking, systemdynamics

In a small Program users insert multiple typed formulas and wire them together in order to create a system of simultaneous equations. And I'd like to introduce runtime type checking, so as to report an error if dimensions do not match

Basical the types can be anything, e.g. `Persons, Money, Money/Period, m^2/s^2` etc, and are entered as strings at runtime

I read about Hindley-Milner type inference, but thought that it's a bit overblown.

My idea was to rely on two rules:

first tokenize, then

```
If (a + b) or (a-b) the dimensions must match! [a] = [b]
```

if a*b then the dimensions are "expanded" or "contracted" in the sense that you keep track of the count of individual dimensions, e.g

```
Person/Year * Money/Year * Money*Year^2 ===> Money(2) Person(1) Year(2) / Year(1)
```

then subtract individual counts, thus leaving `Money(2) Person(1) Year(1)` as `final type`

this could be implemented as a tree walker, where the dimensional contraints are tested per (+/-)-node
then simplifying tho yield the final answer

Is this a good way to solve this issue?

Comment: Assuming your operations are `{+,-,*,/}`, this sounds good to me.